# What can I imply from $\epsilon^\prime(x) \le -x\epsilon(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, error-function

Imagine, that I can prove $$\epsilon^\prime(x) \le -x\epsilon(x)$$ for a function $\epsilon:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R_0^{+}$. Does this imply $$\epsilon(x) \le c e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$ whereby $c \in \mathbb R$ is a constant? (The solution of the DGL $f^\prime(x) = -xf(x)$ is $f(x) = c e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$).

When I also can prove $\epsilon(0) \le \alpha$, does this mean $\epsilon(x) \le \alpha e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$?

Comment: Write it as $(\epsilon e^{x^2/2})' \leq 0$. Now you can integrate it to obtain $\epsilon(x)\leq \epsilon(0)e^{-x^2/2}$ and since $\epsilon(0) \leq \alpha$ we have $\epsilon(x)\leq \alpha e^{-x^2/2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is both true for $x \ge 0$. It even has a name and a Wikipedia page: [Gronwall's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality)